# Can we deploy multiple microservices by using single helm chart by using helm?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Can we deploy multiple microservices by using single template (It includes only one deployment.yml , svc.yml . cm.yml) but we can have multiple values.yml file by using helm?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a deployment question that shoudl be answered in documentation of the framework used.

Comment: I'd recommend a separate chart per service, even if the charts are very similar.  There are a couple of practical problems with "umbrella" charts that have dependencies on multiple other charts (for example, Helm combines dependencies, so you get one database per system rather than a separate database per service) and I also might look for a dedicated tool to handle this.

Comment: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/13379/use-one-helm-chart-for-all-microservices/15579#15579

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think you can.

For example, you could set your `service.yaml` template like below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.service.name }}
spec:
  selector:
    app: {{ .Values.service.name }}
  ports:
  - port: {{ .Values.service.port }}
    targetPort: {{ .Values.service.targetPort }}
```

Specify values in `service1-values.yaml`

```
service
  name: service1
  port: 80
  targetPort: 8080
```

Create similar files for values of other services.

Then install the chart for various services by using the `-f` flag

`helm install -f service1-values.yaml chart-name .`

`helm install -f service2-values.yaml chart-name .`